# How to filter this python dictionary to make 2 new dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the sample input dictionary I have

```
dct={'48689': 'FINNIFTY02JAN24C20900', '46624': 'FINNIFTY09JAN24P20900', '40811': 
'NIFTY14DEC23C20750', '40812': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20750', '40813': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20800', '40814': 
'NIFTY14DEC23P20800', '40817': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20850', '40818': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20850', '40828': 
'NIFTY14DEC23C20900', '40832': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20900', '40834': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20950', '40839': 
'NIFTY14DEC23P20950'}
```

I want to make two new dictionaries **dict_P** and **dict_C** based on following conditions :

- if respective dct value has "23C2" or "23C1 or "24C1" or "24C2" in it
  then corresponding key,value would be assigned to dict_C
- if respective dct value has "23P2" or "23P1" or "24P2" or "24P1" in it then corresponding key,value would be assigned to dict_P

Expected output :

```
dict_C - 
    {'48689': 'FINNIFTY02JAN24C20900', '40811': 
    'NIFTY14DEC23C20750','40813': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20800', '40817': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20850','40828': 
    'NIFTY14DEC23C20900','40834': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20950'}

dict_P - 
    { '46624': 'FINNIFTY09JAN24P20900', '40812': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20750', '40814': 
    'NIFTY14DEC23P20800', '40818': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20850', '40832': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20900', '40839': 
    'NIFTY14DEC23P20950'}
```

I did come up with very simple novice list based solution as follows :

```
    strike_list = []
    CE_list = []
    PE_list = []
    strike_list = list(dct.values())

    arrC = ["23C1", "23C2", "24C2", "24C1"]
    arrP = ["23P1", "23P2", "24P2", "24P1"]
    for i in strike_list:
        for j in arrC:
            if j in i:
                CE_list.append(i)
    print( CE_list)

    for i in strike_list:
        for j in arrP:
            if j in i:
                PE_list.append(i)
    print(PE_list)
```

It works but I want **2 dictionaries** (instead of lists) which has corresponding `key:value` pairs as mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

Don't convert `dct` to a list, iterate over the keys and values with `dct.items()`. Then you can add the key and value to one of the result dictionaries.

Use `any()` rather than a loop to tell if it matches one of the filter lists.

```
dict_C = {}
dict_P = {}
arrC = ["23C1", "23C2", "24C2", "24C1"]
arrP = ["23P1", "23P2", "24P2", "24P1"]

for key, value in dct.items():
    if any(x in value for x in arrC):
        dict_C[key] = value
    elif any(x in value for x in arrP):
        dict_P[key] = value
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the code below, Instead of looping over the array, loop over the dictionary items

Loop over the dictionary items, and search each value against the values you have in arrays.

Then create new dictionaries using the same key value if the values match.

```
dct={'48689': 'FINNIFTY02JAN24C20900', '46624': 'FINNIFTY09JAN24P20900', '40811': 
'NIFTY14DEC23C20750', '40812': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20750', '40813': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20800', '40814': 
'NIFTY14DEC23P20800', '40817': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20850', '40818': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20850', '40828': 
'NIFTY14DEC23C20900', '40832': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20900', '40834': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20950', '40839': 
'NIFTY14DEC23P20950'}

dict_C = {}
dict_P = {}
arrC = ["23C1", "23C2", "24C2", "24C1"]
arrP = ["23P1", "23P2", "24P2", "24P1"]
for key, value in dct.items():
    for item in arrC:
        if item in value:
            dict_C[key] = value
    for item in arrP:
        if item in value:
            dict_P[key] = value
```

dict_C:

```
{'48689': 'FINNIFTY02JAN24C20900',
 '40811': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20750',
 '40813': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20800',
 '40817': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20850',
 '40828': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20900',
 '40834': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20950'}
```

dict_P

```
{'46624': 'FINNIFTY09JAN24P20900',
 '40812': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20750',
 '40814': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20800',
 '40818': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20850',
 '40832': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20900',
 '40839': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20950'}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you could split the dictionary based on a fixed single character (`C` or `P`), if this is the case then use a simple:

```
out = {}
for k, v in dct.items():
    out.setdefault(v[-6], {})[k] = v
```

*NB. if the position is not fixed you can use an alternative strategy to extract the letter, but in any case, if this letter is the sole determinant of how to split, don't use a list of all possibilities.*

Output:

```
{'C': {'48689': 'FINNIFTY02JAN24C20900',
       '40811': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20750',
       '40813': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20800',
       '40817': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20850',
       '40828': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20900',
       '40834': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20950'},
 'P': {'46624': 'FINNIFTY09JAN24P20900',
       '40812': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20750',
       '40814': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20800',
       '40818': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20850',
       '40832': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20900',
       '40839': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20950'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
keywords = {
    "23C1": 0, "23C2": 0, "24C2": 0, "24C1": 0,
    "23P1": 1, "23P2": 1, "24P2": 1, "24P1": 1,
}

result = [{}, {}]

for key, val in dct.items():
    for kw, index in keywords.items():
        if kw in val:
            result[index][key] = val
            break
```

Comment: This is hardly close to what they want. It doesn't match the values by looking for a substring.

Comment: @Barmar: this produces exactly the output the OP expected

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the code. I didn't recognize that the `keywords` dictionary is an alternate representation of `arrC` and `arrP`. Perhaps you should add the code that performs that transformation.

Comment: Don't just post code, explain how it works. If I didn't understand it right away, what hope is there for all the novices?

Comment: It would also be clearer if result were a dictionary like `{'P': {}, 'C': {}}`. Then the values in `keywords` would be `P` and `C` and the relationship would be more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension

```
set_C = {"23C2", "23C1", "24C1", "24C2", "23C2"}
dict_C = {k:v for k,v in dct.items() if any(x in v for x in set_C)}

dict_C
# Out: 
# {'48689': 'FINNIFTY02JAN24C20900',
#  '40811': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20750',
#  '40813': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20800',
#  '40817': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20850',
#  '40828': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20900',
#  '40834': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20950'}
```

Loop once through the original dictionary:

```
dct = {'48689': 'FINNIFTY02JAN24C20900', '46624': 'FINNIFTY09JAN24P20900', 
       '40811': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20750', '40812': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20750', 
       '40813': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20800', '40814': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20800', 
       '40817': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20850', '40818': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20850', 
       '40828': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20900', '40832': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20900', 
       '40834': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20950', '40839': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20950'}

set_P = {"23P1", "23P2", "24P2", "24P1"}
set_C = {"23C1", "23C2", "24C2", "24C1"}

dict_C, dict_P = {}, {}

for k,v in dct.items():
    if any(x in v for x in set_C):
        dict_C[k] = v
    elif any(x in v for x in set_P):
        dict_P[k] = v
```

Comment: Calling it `set_C` is misleading since it's not a `set`.

Comment: @Barmar you're right that's not a Python `set`, I changed the data structure to match the name

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to make two new dictionaries dict_P and dict_C ..."*

Here is an example.

```py
dict_C = {}
dict_P = {}
for k, v in dct.items():
    for x in ['23C2', '23C1', '24C1', '24C2']:
        if x in v:
            dict_C.update({k: v})
            break
    for x in ['23P2', '23P1', '24P2', '24P1']:
        if x in v:
            dict_P.update({k: v})
            break
```

Output

```
dict_C =
   {'40811': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20750',
    '40813': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20800',
    '40817': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20850',
    '40828': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20900',
    '40834': 'NIFTY14DEC23C20950',
    '48689': 'FINNIFTY02JAN24C20900'}

dict_P =
   {'40812': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20750',
    '40814': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20800',
    '40818': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20850',
    '40832': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20900',
    '40839': 'NIFTY14DEC23P20950',
    '46624': 'FINNIFTY09JAN24P20900'}
```